# Opening context menu on tree node causes NodeContextException

Tags: silktest

In my code I select a node from a `SapTree` and

```
String key = tree.findNodeKeyByPath(path);
tree.selectNode(key);
tree.nodeContextMenu(key);
```

but instead of opening a context menu, it results in an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error executing 'NodeContextMenu'. An unexpected COM exception occurred at SAP Frontend Server (). .
    at com.borland.silktest.jtf.internal.Agent.convertException(Agent.java:294)
    at com.borland.silktest.jtf.internal.Agent.invoke(Agent.java:394)
    at com.borland.silktest.jtf.AbstractTestObject.invoke(AbstractTestObject.java:462)
    at com.microfocus.silktest.jtf.sap.SapTree.nodeContextMenu(SapTree.java:1490)
    ...
```

The [nodeContextMenu()](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FNodeContextMenuMethodSapTree_ref.html) documentation is not very helpful regaring potential issues.

How can I open a context menu if not the way I did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception may occur if more than one node is selected, i.e. if a node was already selected before you selected the second one.

To clear all selected nodes, insert a call `tree.unselectAll()` ([Silk documentation](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FUnselectAllMethodSapTree_ref.html))